# Applying input value when event listener was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, event-listener

I have an input with two span "buttons":

```
 <label class="label1" for="adults">Adults:</label>
 <span class="plus"></span>
 <input type="text" id="adults" value="0">
 <span class="minus"></span>
```

Simple JS works for console.log() but doesn't apply that value to the actual input value. Is there any method in JS/JQuery which can handle this?

```
var adultsValue = $('#adults').val();

$('.plus').click(function () {
    if(adultsValue < 5) {
    adultsValue++;
    }
    console.log(adultsValue);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to increment the value or just check it?

Comment: @andre Yes, to increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-assining a value rather than updating the current field's value.

**Snippet with some fixes**

- Store the element `#adults` to avoid a look for that element every time.
- Convert the current value to number.
- Set the new incremented value.

---

```
var $adults = $('#adults');
$('.plus').click(function () {
    var val = Number($adults.val());
    if (val < 5) {
        $adults.val(++val);
    }

    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. Can I ask you 2 general questions?

Comment: 1) $ before variable "adults" just to show that it is JQuery selector?
2) "++val" is a shortcut for "val = val + 1"?

Comment: 1) Yes - 2) Yes, however what's happening is an increment before to the assignation to `$adults.val(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var adults = $('#adults')
var adultsValue = adults.val();

$('.plus').click(function () {
    if(adultsValue < 5) {
       adults.val(adultsValue + 1);
    }
    console.log(adultsValue);
});
```

Comment: There was a problem: when I clicked the "button" the value changed to 01 and then "frizzed"/stopped completely. However, I changed the line:

        "adults.val(adultsValue + 1);"

to:

       "adults.val(++adultsValue); "

like at @Ele snippet and everything works.